# For triangular numbers, how do I check the next input in the equation is greater than the limit?

Tags: python

I have a program where the user inputs a limit, and then prints out the sequence of triangular numbers that are less than or equal to the limit provided. The triangular numbers should be printed out one number per line. However, I cannot solve if e.g. The limit is 18 and the number is currently 15, it will print the next number even though that next number will be greater than the limit, 18.
Here's my code:

```
limit = int(input("Limit: "))
n = 0
x = 1
while x <= limit and (x + 1) * ((x+1) + 1) / 2 <= limit: 
    n = n + 1
    x = n * (n + 1) / 2
    print(int(x))
```

So pretty much what I'm trying to do here is while the number is less than the limit **and** while the next number after that is less than the limit it prints it but doesn't seem to work. Some tips would be so good, I'm pretty stuck, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: see how you need to change your code to `print` at the start of the loop, not at the end.

The effect will be that you'll print *right after you've checked the terminal condition* and so won't be printing any extraneous numbers.

Right now you're checking the terminal condition, then doing some calculation, then printing the result of the calculation (when the terminal condition might no longer hold).